# Is there a way to get an aggregated report of coverage of all my modules in a project with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, build.gradle

So, I have a project structure like this:
project -> modules -> module1 -> src, test module2 -> src, test and so on. Using SonarQube I get the coverage report for all my modules just fine. But my question is is there a way in sonar to get the overall coverage (like a weighted average) of the entire project, rather than for each module?
My root build.gradle file has sonarqube task like so:

````
```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'blah'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"
    }
}
subprojects { project ->
    apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.exclusions", "**/e1/**, **/e2/**, **/e3/**"
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: What about creating a build including the entire project?

Comment: i'm adding the about code in the root build.gradle it self. but i see the sonar report per module. Can I have like an averaage report for the entire project?